# Dictionary is not freeing memory

Tags: c#, dictionary, directory, traversal

I have a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>>
```

And a method which traverses directories and saves the information in that dictionary

```
public void TraverseDirectory(string startDir)
{
    //this.CreateNewFileWatcher(startDir);
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> dirsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> filesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    Stack<DirectoryInfo> currentDirectorries = new Stack<DirectoryInfo>();
    DirectoryInfo startDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(startDir);
    currentDirectorries.Push(startDirInfo);
    while (currentDirectorries.Count > 0)
    {
        var dir = currentDirectorries.Pop();
        this.AddNewDir(dir, dirsDictionary);
        try
        {
            var currentDirs = dir.GetDirectories();
            foreach (var currentDir in currentDirs)
            {
                currentDirectorries.Push(currentDir);
                try
                {
                    var files = currentDir.GetFiles();
                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        this.AddNewFile(file, filesDictionary);
                    }
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }
    }

    dirsDictionary.Clear();
    filesDictionary.Clear();
}
```

Basically the AddNewDir and AddNewFile methods add the files/dirs to the dictionaries, they are used more for testing purposes. As you can see the dictionaries are only alive in the method, however after that they do not free the memory, which raises to 100mb in good cases. I am saving that info to a MemoryMappedFiles, and the information in there is temporary.

Do you have any idea why the memory is not being freed ?

Regards

Comment: The .NET garbage collector takes care of this. It's unpredictable when it runs.

Comment: How are you measuring the memory usage? Often memory released within a process will not be returned to the system, but kept in the process for future allocations (it is expensive to get more memory from the OS).

Comment: I tried with GC and task manager but what you guys said makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET doesn't free the memory if it doesn't really need. In a tight cycle it can be quite common to see the memory go up by tens of mb. If you want to check if the memory is reclaimable try adding:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Note that in the end normally you don't need to use these commands. The GC will free the memory if it needs more memory (or when the program pauses for some reasons)

Comment: In this case just a Thread.Sleep(for some millisecondes) can allows the GC to free memory ?